# Error occurred in generating events. Caused by Error occured in execute query

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I'm migrating from an on-premise TFS 2010 to VSO. I get the following error:

> Error in execution of Job : CIR| CIR| TFS Source 1436704819005 ALM TFS 1436704819007 'CIR' Test Suite  CIR| TFS Source 1436704819005 ALM TFS 1436704819007 Test Suite
>
> OpsHub-012300: Error occurred in generating events. Caused by Error occured in execute query : Select * from TestSuite where LastUpdated > '1969-12-31 01:00:00.000' order by LastUpdated caused by:   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSTestSuiteClient.executeQuery(String query, DateTime afterTime, String lastProcessId, Int32 limit) in e:\OVSMUBranch\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSTestSuiteUtility.cs:line 897

**Screenshot:**

[image: OpsHub failure log]

---

What does this error message mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you please send us your logs located at <installation-path>/logs at ovsmu@opshub.com

Comment: Logs have been sent.